# Mosquito MQTT Thingsboard and Thingsboard IoT-gateway on same server

Tags: mqtt

It would be much appreciated if someone could tell me the settings to run Mosquito MQTT and Thingsboard with Thingsboard IoT-gateway on the same server.

Mosquito is receiving on port 1883 which is working. Were do I need to configure the ports (must be different, right?) between IoT-Gateway and Thingsboard and how do I configure IoT-Gateway that it is connecting to Thingsboard?

The Thingsboard documentation is not helping here.

Comment: Can't you change port of Mosquito, instead ?

Comment: It is also about the communicatios between gateway and thingsboard.

Comment: Which ports are you trying to configure?  Why?  A port is only an issue when its on the same IP address, eg if you had two mosquitto servers on one ip address, then you would need to use different port for one of them.

Comment: Which Documentation you are following, please update it in question for more clarity. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can Configure Mosquito MQTT and Thingsboard IoT-gateway on the same host by configuring the MQTT port different for both the application. Below is a sample configuration which uses default port for Mosquito MQTT (i.e 1883) and port 1893 for Thingsboard IoT-gateway, also you need to configure all Thingsboard device to new port 1893

[image: Host Configuration]

Configuring ThingsBoard IOT
The configuration file is located in the installation folder for Windows and /etc/tb-gateway/conf for Linux host.

Open the tb-gateway.yml in you favorite text editor and change value of port (under gateways:, tenents:, connection:) to 1893 save the file and restart the Thingsboard IOT server, also note change all ThingsBoard device to use the new port 1893

This is the link to the [ThingsBoard Document](https://thingsboard.io/docs/iot-gateway/getting-started/#step-8-connect-to-external-mqtt-broker)